# Is the application/octet-stream MIME type safe for uploading?

Tags: php, file-upload, mime-types

We have a server side PHP script to handle file uploads from an Android app. This script identifies the mime type of AMR files as `application/octet-stream`. We have an array containing some MIME types that script uses to check whether the file is safe or not. I'm not sure whether to add `application/octet-stream` to this array or not. Is it safe? Or do we have to check this type of file more thoroughly? If yes, how?

Comment: please show me your code

Comment: I made some grammar fixes and tried to clarify the languague of your question. I also improved the formatting. Please don't end every sentence with an exclamation mark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`application/octet-stream` just means "generic binary", so whether or not it is "safe" depends more on what you are doing with the file - just like every kind of data accepted from a user.

If you are just storing the file for Download later, it is safe.